# How do I shift the elements inside a Rust vector to the right and put the out-of-bounds element at the beginning?

Tags: rust

I am trying to move the elements in a vector to the right and then place the out of bounds element back at the beginning; a rotation of the vector.

This is pseudocode to move the first element in the vector 1 step. Since the vector is only 5 elements, the `5` goes back to the start of the vector:

```
let V = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
A = V.move[0].cycle();
A = [5, 1, 2, 3, 4];
```

The `A = V.move[0].cycle();` is my attempt at this, but since Rust doesn't rotate if the index is out of bounds, it can be hard to implement.

In Python, it's possible to use the `pop` function with lists:

```
>>>m = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>m += [m.pop(0)]
>>>m
[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
```

Using a for loop, it's possible to shift all elements to be `[5, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. Is there an equivalent to the `pop` function in Rust? 
It would even be better if there is a function to shift elements all together.

Comment: Hi there! Unfortunately, your question is a bit hard to understand. What do you mean by "cycle back"? What is this `V.move[0]` syntax supposed to do? Where is the `.cycle()` method from? Do I understand you correct in that you want to "rotate" the vector? I.e. put the last element at the start? Please [edit] your question to clarify these things. Then we can answer :)

Comment: Look at the `rotate_right` and `rotate_left` methods. If I understand your question correctly then they do exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @interjay That's exactly what i am looking for. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are looking for [`[T]::rotate_right`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.rotate_right) and [`[T]::rotate_left`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.rotate_left). Example ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2b37821b720c1072a30ce061abd851ec)):

```
let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
v.rotate_right(1);
println!("{:?}", v);
```

This outputs:

```
[5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If you find yourself calling `rotate_*` a lot, you should consider using a different data structures, as those methods are linear time operations. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59273079/2408867), for example.

Answer (score 15):

[`VecDeque`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html) is a collection similar to a `Vec` but optimized for adding/removing elements at either end. Just like slices, it has `rotate_{left,right}` methods, but those are more efficient than `Vec`'s (`O(min(mid, len() - mid))` time for `VecDeque`, vs. `O(len())` time for `Vec`):

```rust
use std::collections::VecDeque;

fn main() {
    let mut v = (1..6).collect::<VecDeque<_>>();
    v.rotate_right(1);
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

([Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d136c96ddb0e1003c6732bf2187bf0bb))